# JavaFX self-contained apps are missing the Cipher cryptographic service?

Tags: java, deployment, cryptography, javafx-2, self-contained

For some reason, **JavaFX** does not seem to currently support any algorithms for the **Cipher** cryptographic service when the application is executed after the **self-contained** deployment, as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#BCGGACFA).

Given this code:

```
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public final class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage)
    {
        final ObservableList<String> ol = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        final ListView<String> lv = new ListView(ol);

        for (final Iterator<String> iter = Security.getAlgorithms("Cipher").iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
            ol.add(iter.next());

        final Scene s = new Scene(lv, 500, 400);

        stage.setScene(s);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

There is no problem getting populated output with various algorithms if this code is ran locally through the *java launcher*, but gives an **empty** list if the application has been packaged as **self-contained**.

However, I have also stumbled upon this:

> Only a subset of Java Runtime is included by default. Some optional
>   and rarely used files are excluded to reduce the package size, such as
>   all executables. If you need something that is not included by
>   default, then you need to copy it in as a post-processing step. For
>   installable packages, you can do this from the config script that is
>   executed after populating the self-contained application folder. See
>   Section 6.3.3, "Customization Using Drop-In Resources."

Could the quoted paragraph be the probable cause? What kind of workaround would be needed in order to get this functionality included into the **self-contained** runtime?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you package your app with an external `Provider` such as bouncy castle?

Comment: I believe that might be a plausible option, even though, to be frank, I'd prefer a native solution that resides in the **JDK**, instead of relying on external dependencies. I will try researching this particular matter more and if unsuccessful - I will try the libs provided by the bouncy castle. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Looking at https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_cookbook_using_drop the bundled JCE isn't packaged by default.

Comment: @Qwerky Sounds like enough info for a self-contained answer :P

Comment: @Qwerky if you don't mind - add your comment as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_cookbook_using_drop) the bundled JCE isn't packaged by default.